# Dollar Before the Federal Reserve

Tags: federal-reserve

A lot of bloggers like to write that the dollar has lost 90+% of its value against a basket of goods since the Fed was created.  Without a comparison to the former dollar, that's a meaningless statement.  Is there data that show the dollar's appreciation/depreciation before the Fed took over?

[Example of this assertion.](http://www.usinflationcalculator.com/frequently-asked-questions-faqs/#HowInflationCalculatorWorks)

I am not saying its true, but rather, I don't see this calculators showing what the Dollar did against these same basket of goods before the Fed over time.

Comment: Just a thought: Wouldn't that have something to do with abandoning the gold standard?

Comment: Possibly; my question though is really about is there any proof that the Dollar did better when it was under the previous system that wasn't controlled by the Fed?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:BankPanicUSA)  suggests 16 financial crises and banking panics in the United States before 1913 compared with 2 after then (1929 and 2007-08).

Comment: The dollar appreciates/depreciates in relation to other currencies. You can't say that the dollar appreciated/depreciated without mentioning the other currency. As written, your question is not answerable.

Comment: @rocinante It says a basket of goods, but when stated that way, it's just describing inflation.